# Racket - cannot send prefab struct through place channel when there's a contract on it

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having an issue where I can't send a prefab struct across a place channel if the struct was imported with a contract. Here's a complete example:

```
#lang racket

(module structs racket

  (provide
   example-without-contract
   (contract-out [struct example-with-contract ([thing string?])]))

  (struct example-without-contract (thing) #:prefab)
  (struct example-with-contract (thing) #:prefab))

(require 'structs)
(displayln (format "Can send example-without-contract: ~A"
                   (place-message-allowed? (example-without-contract "abc"))))
(displayln (format "Can send example-with-contract: ~A"
                   (place-message-allowed? (example-with-contract "abc"))))
```

With Racket 6.8, this prints:

```
Can send example-without-contract: #t
Can send example-with-contract: #f
```

There's nothing in the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/places.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fplace..rkt%29._place-message-allowed~3f%29%29) that mentions contracts. Is this an actual limitation, and if so, is there any way to work around it? (Short of just creating another struct to send through the channel, I guess).

Comment: Given that contracts themselves cannot be sent through place channels, it makes sense to me that a struct with a contract attached to it would not be able to be sent through a place channel, either. I don’t believe there is a way to work around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err....since this a prefab struct (and you want to make it send it across a place), all of your data is flat, so you could just as easily make your prefab struct by hand. For example:

```
> (define s '#s(example-with-contract "abc"))
> (example-with-contract? s)
#t
> (displayln (format "Can send example-with-contract: ~A"
               (place-message-allowed? s)))
Can send example-with-contract: #t
```

Kindof odd, but hey, you can still make this and have your checks (because again, they are still flat.) In fact, you can even define a function to make it serialize for you:

```
(require racket/struct)
(define (serialize-prefab s)
  (define key (prefab-struct-key s))
  (define elems (struct->list s))
  (apply make-prefab-struct key elems))
```

And now, you can send your prefab struct in a place message,

```
> (displayln (format "Can send example-with-contract: ~A"
               (place-message-allowed?
                 (serialize-prefab (example-with-contract "abc")))))
Can send example-without-contract: #t
```